# SOSL email search is unable to locate a record in Salesforce immediately after the record has been saved (AWS and Salesforce)

Tags: sosl, duplicate-matching-rule, amazon-aws

I am using 2 platforms to do Extract , Transform, Load (ETL):

1. Salesforce (SF)
2. AWS

> I need to ingest taxonomy CSV files based on specific campaigns  - called
> MVIs  - into Salesforce. There are duplicate records in the csv file but
> they differ from each other because they have different campaign IDs
> as well as different unique keys.
> Since we may have to load a record into separate campaigns, we may have two record entries within the CSV file.

**Process:**

1. An SA integration loads the files onto an SFTP placing the files into
   an S3 bucket.
2. A Lambda processes the file in the S3 bucket to make sure it's an MVI file
3. Another lambda then processes the file data per record row and looks for an email match inside SF's existing contact and lead records.
4. If there is a match, then the SF record is updated with the taxonomy file data and placed into the campaign indicated on the file record.
5. If there is no match, then an attempt is made to insert the record into SF as a new lead and add it to the  campaign indicated on the file record.
6. If a file record has an Account ID but the email address is not found, then create a new contact record and ingest that into the campaign indicated on the file record.

**Issue:**

> When I manually drop these files into S3 bucket, the functionality works well. The
> duplicate records seem to ingest their records into their respective
> different campaigns. However, when the SA Integration loads the files
> into the bucket, SF throws a Duplicate Exception  because when the
> integration tries to find the email address of the 2nd duplicate
> record in SF -  using a SOSL statement - it doesn't seem to find it
> *even though it saved the record earlier when it was loaded into the
> first set of campaign IDs*. I also saw this same issue when I separated
> the duplicate records into two different taxonomy files such that each
> file contained no dupes. When I tested this theory by manually dropping the
> files onto the S3 bucket , SF had no problem successfully adding all
> records into the correct respective campaigns. However when the SA integration loaded
> the files, there were SF duplicate errors.

**Questions:**

> Q) IS there some sort of lag /latency issue that occurs when the SA
> integration drops the files on S3 as opposed to when I drop them
> manually myself?
>
> Q) What would be the best overall timing solution if this is a latency
> issue?

> Here is my Lambda code that searches for the existence of a SF record
> via email :  Thanks much !!

```
def mvi_pre_parser(recordInfo,Id=None,Email=None):
        try:
            Type = 'New'
            foundRec = False
            print('INSIDE: mvi_pre_parser') 
            info = []
        
        info = get_info_email_id(recordInfo,Id=Id, Email=Email)
        print('<<  FOUND  EMAIL IN SF?  >>', str(info[0]).lower())
        if Id is not None and Id != '' and Id != 'null':
            print('<< ID>>', Id)
            Type = salesforce.determine_record_type(Id)
        elif str(info[0]).lower() != 'new':
            Id = str(info[1])
            Type = str(info[0])
        elif 'Account_ID' in recordInfo and str(info[0]).lower() == 'new':
            Id = recordInfo['Account_ID']
            Type = salesforce.determine_record_type(Id)
               
        result = check_parse_file_weber(Type, recordInfo, Id)
        print(result)
        #return False
        if result[0]:
            if Id is not None and Id != '' and Id != 'null':
                recordInfo['Id'] = result[1]
            return (True,result[1])
        else:
            return (False,'-')
    except Exception as e:
        print('in Exception handler for MVI Pre Parser')
        print(e)
```

> Here is the code that contains the SOSL search to locate that record
> via email:

```
 def search_by_email(self,info,Email,User=None):
        print('search_by_email')
        if Email != '' and Email != None and Email != 'Null':
            #Weed out all of the invalid emails that this record could contain which will force Contact, Lead, or Account search matching for this record. 
            if '@NOEMAIL' in Email.upper() or 'NONE@' in Email.upper() or '@NONE' in Email.upper() or 'FAKE@' in Email.upper() or 'FAKE' in Email.upper() or 'NOEMAIL@' in Email.upper() or \
            '@NOEMAIL' in Email.upper() or '@FAKE.COM' in Email.upper() or  'INVALID' in Email.upper() :
                if 'CONSTELLATION.COM.INVALID' not in Email.upper() and '@EXELONCORP.COM.INVALID' not in Email.upper(): #Discern the 2 good Invalid lower org email suffixes from the bad ones.
                    #if a_bad_email in Email.upper():
                    print('<< FOUND BAD EMAIL >>')
                    print(Email.upper())
                    return('New', '')
            Email = Email.replace('-','\-')
            Email = Email.replace('&','\&')
            print(Email)
            if User == None:
                self.query = self.__sf.search("""
                    FIND {%s}
                    IN EMAIL FIELDS
                    RETURNING Lead(Id,FirstName,LastName WHERE IsConverted = FALSE LIMIT 1), Contact(Id,FirstName,LastName)
                    """ % Email)
                print(self.query)
                self.result = self.query['searchRecords']
                print(self.result)
                if self.result == []:
                    print('in empty result')
                    self.Id = ''
                    self.Type = 'New'
                    self.fname = ''
                    self.lname = ''
                else: #VERIFY THAT IF THERE ARE MULTILE PEOPLE USING A STAFF EMAIL THAT THE RIGHHT PERSON GETS RETURNED
                    print(' <<< in not empty result >>>', len(self.result))
                    if str(info['LastName']).lower() != str(self.result[0]['LastName']).lower() and len(self.result)  == 1:
                        self.Id = ''
                        self.Type = 'New'
                        self.fname = ''
                        self.lname = ''
                        return(self.Type, self.Id,self.fname,self.lname)
                    elif len(self.result) > 1:
                        total = len(self.result)
                        foundRec = False
                        for idx in range(total):
                            if str(self.result[idx]['LastName']) == str(info['LastName']):
                                foundRec = True
                                self.Id = self.result[idx]['Id']
                                self.Type = self.result[idx]['attributes']['type']
                                self.fname = self.result[idx]['FirstName']
                                self.lname = self.result[idx]['LastName']
                                return(self.Type, self.Id,self.fname,self.lname)
                        if foundRec != True:
                            self.Id = ''
                            self.Type = 'New'
                            self.fname = ''
                            self.lname = ''
                            return(self.Type, self.Id,self.fname,self.lname)
                    self.Id = self.result[0]['Id']
                    self.Type = self.result[0]['attributes']['type']
                    self.fname = self.result[0]['FirstName']
                    self.lname = self.result[0]['LastName']
                return(self.Type, self.Id,self.fname,self.lname)
```

> Here are the AWS logs on the lambda integration showing the SF
> Duplicate error excpetions thrown by the Matching Rules (IN these
> examples Nicole was already  added successfully the first time but the
> second time her email was not in SF and came back as a null result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: SOSL indexing is asynchronous and uses a mechanism shared by all tenants. It can take a while (certainly more than seconds and certainly into minutes). I can't find it right now, but there is documentation explaining this available publicly.

Comment: @Vijaya Kapadam for providing this:  I knew it may have been something based on timing. I will look into what you have suggested to see if I can find any thing., What I was proposing is to set a time between MVI file ingestions of at least 60 seconds (our client doesn't load many per day on our S3 bucket) . This will mimic what I do when I test MVI file ingestions manually. Maybe that may solve the issue? I'll just sleep the AWS integration for 60 seconds whenever an MVI file is being ingested.